# consulta mysql que sume las atenciones por dia y de cada usuario

Tags: mysql, select

Tengo dos tablas la de consulta (id_consulta, id_doctor, fecha_consulta, costo ) y la de doctores(id_doctor, nombre ), necesito hacer una consulta que me muestre lo los siguientes datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde en la primer columna me muestre la fechas y en el siguiente renglon el nombre de los doctores y que sume las consultas por dia y el total del costo de todas las consultas.

Comment: Y eso donde lo quieres presentar??? Porque la consulta es un join a esas 2 tablas, agrupas por fecha y por doctor luego sumas el costo y haces un count. Pero para que se te vea en ese formato, que es la parte difícil, lo más práctico es hacerlo desde php, excel, java,c# o lo que sea que estes ocupando.

Comment: necesito hacer una vista en mysql, y que me lo muestre asi como se ve en la imagen

Answer (score 0):

Haz uso de la cláusula `JOIN` para combinar ambas tablas, `GROUP BY` para agrupar por médico y por día, y de las funciones `COUNT` y `SUM` para obtener el número de consultas y coste total.

```
SELECT
    c.fecha_consulta AS Dia,
    d.nombre AS Doctor,
    COUNT(c.id_consulta) AS Consultas,
    SUM(c.costo) AS Total
FROM consultas AS c
    LEFT JOIN doctores AS d
    ON d.id_doctor = c.id_doctor
GROUP BY c.id_doctor, c.fecha_consulta
```

El resultado no está exactamente en el formato que tú indicas porque es muy complejo mostrar las fechas agrupadas de esa forma utilizando únicamente SQL.

No sé cómo de importante es obtener exactamente ese formato, pero como indicó @Yussef, para mostrar los datos en un formato tan específico es posible que sea conveniente utilizar otras tecnologías.

Answer (score 0):

```
select R.Dia, R.consultas, R.Total from(
select C.fecha_consulta, D.Nombre as Dia, count(*) as consultas, sum(costo) as Total, 1 as Orden from consulta as C
join doctores as D on C.id_doctor=D.id_doctor
group by C.fecha_consulta, C.id_doctor 
union
select C.fecha_consulta, C.fecha_consulta as Dia, count(*) as consultas, sum(costo) as Total, 0 as Orden from consulta as C
group by C.fecha_consulta) as R
order by R.fecha_consulta, R.Orden
```

Yo creo que algo así podría resultar, tienes 2 consultas:

1. La primera que te trae los datos como normalmente uno los traería
2. La segunda solo las fechas

A ambas le agregas un campo Orden, 1 para la primera y 0 para la segunda. En la segunda consulta repites el campo fecha
Luego las unes y haces otro select para mostrar solo lo que te interesa, ordenando por fecha y por 'Orden'

Otra versión del código, la primera debería mostrar los totales diarios, esta debería mostrar exactamente como tu dibujo

```
select R.Dia, R.consultas, R.Total from(
select C.fecha_consulta, D.Nombre as Dia, count(*) as consultas, sum(costo) as Total, 1 as Orden from consulta as C
join doctores as D on C.id_doctor=D.id_doctor
group by C.fecha_consulta, C.id_doctor 
union
select C.fecha_consulta, C.fecha_consulta as Dia, '' as consultas, '' as Total, 0 as Orden from consulta as C
group by C.fecha_consulta) as R
order by R.fecha_consulta, R.Orden
```